# List all types declared by module in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I list all the types that are declared by a module in Ruby?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the *constants* method defined in the *Module* module. From the Ruby documentation:

> Module.constants => array
>
> Returns an array of the names of all
>   constants defined in the system. This
>   list includes the names of all modules
>   and classes.
>
> p Module.constants.sort[1..5]
>
> produces:
>
> ["ARGV", "ArgumentError", "Array",
>   "Bignum", "Binding"]

You can call *constants* on any module or class you would like.

```
p Class.constants
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can grab an array of the names of all constants and classes defined in a module by doing

> > > ModuleName.constants